# Windows 10 Error 0xC1900200

Tags: windows-10

I'm already aware that many have had this issue and that solutions already exist, but I haven't found one that works for my situation. If I had read correctly, this error is due to some kind of reserved partition being too full. The thing is that I have Windows 10 installed on a 64-GiB partition on an external drive attached to a MacBook. I don't really know where the "hidden partition" is that's supposed to get the letter Y assigned to it. I installed Windows 10 with the boot and system partitions on the same partition, and there is plenty of space left.

By the way, Windows 10 is already up and running, but this error arises upon attempting to upgrade to a newer version in order to install the Creators Update.

Edit: The disk on which Windows 10 is installed was originally intended for just Linux. All of its partitions were created and edited using only `gparted`. It currently contains (0) a Linux partition formatted as ext4, (1) an extended partition containing two logical partitions, both for storage, (2) the Windows 10 partition formatted as NTFS, and (3) a Linux swap partition that I plan on swapping out (heh) for more storage or possibly expanding my Windows 10 partition to make use of the rest of the hard drive. The internal drive is solely Mac stuff. I use rEFInd from an external USB to boot into Windows.

Comment: Can you include more information as to what you steps you have already taken to troubleshoot this? More information on your exact partition layout would also be helpful.

Comment: I added some more information for you.

Comment: C1900200 = "Setup.exe has detected that the machine does not meet the minimum system requirements." your strange setup confuses Windows. MS never tests such strange configs. Reinstall Win10v1703 from a proper ISO to avoid this upgrade hassle

Comment: Well, I did use a Windows 10 installation ISO, if that counts.

Comment: but you seam to try the upgrade. Do a clean install when you boot from ISO/USB drive